# How to ensure the hashcode does not equal another object of same type by chance

Tags: java, hashcode

I'm experimenting with the copy constructor to clone vehicle objects. I am overriding the `toString()` method of a class called Vehicle just for presentation sake. But the clones must be unique and completely independent.

Is it a guarantee that if I create thousands of clones of the Vehicle object that all of them will be unique when checked against each other using the `equals()` method? I am under the impression that every object that is created, is guaranteed to always have a new and unique hashcode that would never equal another when I use the `equals()` method for comparison.

**EDITED:**
My question really is, would using the default equals() method to compare my 100000 clones ensure that each one is in-fact unique and equals() will always return false???

```
public class App {

    public List<Vehicle> buildCar(String type, int hp)
    {
        List<Vehicle> vs = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        Vehicle vObject = new Vehicle();
        vObject.setHorsePower(hp);
        vObject.setType(type);

        Vehicle newV = new Vehicle(vObject);
        vs.add(newV);
        vs.add(vObject);
        return vs;
    }   

    public static void main(String args[]){
        App ap = new App();
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

        vehicles.addAll(ap.buildCar("car",100));

        Vehicle v1 = vehicles.get(0);
        Vehicle v2 = vehicles.get(1);

        System.out.println(v1.equals(v2)); // prints false.
                //System.out.println(v2.hashCode());

    }
}
```

Comment: A hashcode is not meant to be unique, only `As much as is reasonably practical`.

Comment: So does equals() method by default use hashcode to check equality? How can I ensure the clones are individual in my java code checks using methods like equals()?

Comment: Read the javadoc of each method. Your `equals()` (`Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.`) should not use `hashcode()` (`Returns a hash code value for the object.`) internally.

Comment: Yea but look at what the doc says for equals() method: `Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.` Basically my question here is this: Can I depend on the default equals() method to be correct when using it to compare 100000 clones with each other?

Comment: No, you cannot depend on the default equals. Read the full javadoc entry. The default `equals` simply checks reference equality with `==`.

Comment: So what's the alternative Sotirios?

Comment: Implement your own `equals`...

Comment: Well Sibbo is telling me somthing else. He is saying use ==.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between reference equality and value equality? Use `==` for reference equality, use `equals`, implemented correctly, for value equality.

Comment: I'm not sure what would apply here in my case. I have a bunch of clones of the vehicle object. Could you elaborate as an answer on my question as it relates to equivalence by reference and value. What would the difference be for my example of a bunch of clone vehicles? I'm not knowledgeable about the difference actually between value and reference.

Comment: Reference equality wouldn't work since cloning creates new objects, and thus new references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals method will always distinguish between equal (whatever that means) and not-equal with 100% accuracy.  Comparing hash codes is only guaranteed to mean "not equal" if the hashcodes mismatch -- equal hash codes does not mean "equal" will be true.

The one unbreakable rule for hashcodes is that if two objects return true for "equal" then their hashcodes must match.

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong. The `hashCode()` function returns an `int`. So when creating `2^32 + 1` objects, at least one hash code will appear twice.

Per default (If you don't overwrite the `hashCode()` function), objects will have their address in memory as hash code. This is why you get the impression it is unique. You are creating not enough objects to allocate enough memory to get two equal hash codes.

---

> How can I make sure the objects that will be generated via cloning, are in-fact completely independent and unique?

Independence and uniqueness are different criteria.

Independence means simply that an object and its clone do not share state.  So if (for example) your `Vehicle` objects have mutable components, you need to ensure that your `clone` method clones the components as well.

Uniqueness requires more information.  Specifically, it depends on what you are using as your "test" for uniqueness.

- If you are using `==` as your test for uniqueness, then any implementation of `clone` that creates a new object will satisfy the requirement.  (The normal expectation of `clone` is that it *will* create a new object ...)
- If you are using `equals` as your test for uniqueness, then it depends on how you define the `equals` method.  The default implementation of `equals` uses `==`.  If you override `equals` to test based on object fields, then if you want the clones to be unique (according to `equals`) you need some kind of identifier field that *serves as the objects identity* ... and arrange that your `clone` method gives each clone a new identifier value.  (And that means that simply delegating to `Object.clone()` is not sufficient.)

---

> My question really is, would using the default equals() method to compare my 100000 clones ensure that each one is in-fact unique and equals() will always return false?

Yes ... for any reasonable implementation of `clone()`.

The default implementation of Java `equals(Object)` does the same test as Java `==`, and that will only give you `true` if the two operands are the same object reference.

Comment: Okay so I don't want to build a software on this scary assumption that I have. How can I make sure the objects that will be generated via cloning, are in-fact completely independent and unique? I want to be able to check for that in my java code.

Comment: Well, you can check for reference if you want to do that. Just use `==` instead of `equals(Object)`. Every object has a unique reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any correct `clone` implementation, the result is a object different from the original (i.e. `original.clone() != original`).

The `equals` implementation of Object checks if the Objects are identical (the return value is the same as for ==), i.e. it doesn't return true for a clone as long as `clone()` is correctly implemented.
Basically you can think of o.equals(o2) as a check, if the 2 objects the variables o and o2 reference occupy the same memory. (still talking of the non-overriden equals implementation)

Therefore clones and the original will be pairwise different, if you check with equals.